# Paste VBA recordset into excel?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

If I had an SQL recordset returned to me in VBA is there an easy way I can just paste the values to the spreadsheet without having to loop through etc?

Comment: You can use the `Range.CopyFromRecordSet` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Oracle InProc Server" and OraDynaset you would use something like the following snippet.

```
Dim QueryResults As OraDynaset
Set QueryResults = Label_DB.CreateDynaset(SQL_String, 0&)
QueryResults.CopyToClipboard
Selection.Paste
```

The default behaviour for CopyToClipboard is to place TAB (ASCII 9) as the column separator and ENTER (ASCII 13) as the row separator.